# If the bowler has exhausted his quota of bouncers for an over, is the batsman out if he nicks a bouncer and gets caught?

Tags: rules, cricket

In all forms of cricket, the number of bouncers per over is limited. For example, quoting from the [current One Day International playing conditions](https://pulse-static-files.s3.amazonaws.com/ICC/document/2017/10/05/498b5049-f7cf-4adf-8562-6abe43cdae8f/ICC-Men-s-ODI-Playing-Conditions-2017-Code-FINAL-051017.pdf):

> 41.6.1.5 A fast short-pitched delivery is defined as a ball, which passes or would have passed above the
>   shoulder height of the striker standing upright at the popping crease.
>
> [...]
>
> 41.6.1.8 In the event of a bowler bowling more than two fast short-pitched deliveries in an over as
>   defined in clause 41.6.1.5 above, the umpire at the bowler’s end shall call and signal No ball on
>   each occasion.

If the batsman manages to hit a bouncer, when the bowler has already exhausted his quota of bouncers per over, and the ball is caught, will the batsman be out or is it a no ball?

Answer (score 2):

No, the batsman cannot be out caught. A no ball due to exceeding the number of bouncers per over is still a no ball and [Law 21.18](https://www.lords.org/mcc/laws-of-cricket/laws/law-21-no-ball/) is *very* clear on this:

> When No ball has been called, neither batsman shall be out under any of the Laws except 34 (Hit the ball twice), 37 (Obstructing the field) or 38 (Run out).)